# Draw / Write on an image more than one line - EmguCV (OpenCV) does not recognize new line char

Tags: c#, opencv, draw, emgucv

I'm trying to Draw a string that have more than one line at a EmguCV (OpenCV C# wraper) Image. But it seams that EmguCV doesn't recognize the new line "\r\n" characters.

How can achieve that? Alternatively, how can I get the text height, so I can set the location for the next string manually?

```
StringBuilder imageComments = new StringBuilder();
imageComments.AppendLine("Camera status");
imageComments.AppendLine("Shutter: " + shutter);
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, Byte> img = new Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
Point location = new Point(30, 30);
MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3f, 0.3f);
Gray color = new Gray(255);
img.Draw(imageComments.ToString(), ref font, location, color);
```

Comment: Not much EmguCV users here. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own function that parses the paragraph into individual lines and then produce the y-displacement needed for each row. If I remember correctly, the default font size is 16 pixels.

```
void myDrawMultiLineText(string InputParagraph, Point Origin)
{
vector<string> LinesOfText = myParse(InputParagraph,"\n");
for (int i=0;i<LinesOfText.size(); ++i)
    DrawText(CurrentLine[i], Origin.x, Origin.y + i*16);
}
```